# Vue PWA TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tap') error

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps

i'am getting this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tap')**


I added with **vue add pwa** command to my application the pwa, and i am getting this error.


I tried to delete my node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstalling it.


If you know the solution pls leave a command, thx

Answer (score 2):

It could be the version you are using.
Looking at this GitHub issue [Vue Cli Issue 7019](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/7019) it appears that other have had a similar issue.

This was the solution discovered on the thread

> I had the same issue, downgrading to @vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "4.5.17"
> solved it.

The above has also solved it for me.